# What is wrong with my proof of Law of Large Numbers?

Tags: probability-theory

Need help in deriving variance for LLN, but am getting something wrong here, can you help point out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks a ton!

For i.i.d random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
Let $X=\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and it's mean be $\mu$(from LLN) then
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(X)& =E[(X-\mu)^2]\\[10pt]
& =E[X^2]-\mu^2\\[10pt]
& =E\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^2\right]-\mu^2\\[10pt]
& =E\left[\frac{1}{n^2} \left( \sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^2\right]-\mu^2\\[10pt]
& =\frac{1}{n^2}E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^2\right]-\mu^2\\[10pt]
& =\frac{1}{n^2}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2+\sum_{i,j=1,i\neq j}^{i,j=n} X_iX_j\right]-\mu^2\\[10pt]
& =\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i^2]+\sum_{i,j=1,i\neq j}^{i,j=n}E[X_iX_j]\right)-\mu^2\\[10pt]
& =\frac{1}{n^2}(n\sigma^2+(n^2-n)\mu^2-n^2\mu^2)\\[10pt]
& =\frac{1}{n^2}(n\sigma^2-n\mu^2)\\[10pt]
& =\frac{\sigma^2-\mu^2}{n}
\end{align}

Comment: How is this a proof of LLN???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E[X_i^2]\ne \sigma^2$$
But should be
$$E[X_i^2] = \sigma^2+\mu^2$$

Comment: ah! right argh, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You say "from LLN", but you are not using LLN anywhere.

Moreover, it's much easier to do this:
$$
\text{Var}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum X_{i}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum\text{Var}\left(X_{i}\right)=\frac{n\sigma^{2}}{n^{2}}=\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n}.
$$

Comment: Yes, agree but I went down that rabbit hole and something wasn't making sense. I used "from LLN" for assuming mean of X to be the same as mean of any $X_i$

Comment: The LLN is about the limit of averaged sums as $n\rightarrow \infty$. There are no limits in your question. All you need to assume is that $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are i.i.d. with finite variance $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Now I see where I was wrong in quoting LLN, I never took $n\to\infty$, I should've just stated it as sum of i.i.d random variables. Apologies, I came across this while heading to LLN.

Comment: No need to apologize, I was just clarifying for your benefit :-)